# python IDE spyder ignoring indentation - sometimes

Tags: python, spyder

Spyder apparently ignores the indentation of a `pass` statement if and only if the pass statement is the last statement in that indentation block.

**Debugging the following will directly jump to debug point #2, ignoring #1**. It shouldn't enter the else at all though. Kinda annoying when debugging.

It will not print "What?!" (phew!)

```
for j in range(10): #j = 0, never enters any higher number
    k=0
    for i in range(5): #i goes up to i = 2
        while i==2: #then enters here
            k+=1 #k increases to 3
            if k>2:
                break #then when k is 3 this breaks the while
        if k>2:
            break #this breaks the for after the while broke
    else: # anything inside this shouldnt be executed because the for was broken
        pass #add a debug point (#1) here
        print('What?!')
        pass #and another debug point (#2) here
```

Is that per design or a bug? And if yes, why?

It doesn't happen in this case:

```
for j in range(10):
    k=0
    for i in range(5):
        while i==2:
            k+=1
            if k>2:
                break
        if k>2:
            break
    else:
        pass
        print('What?!')
        pass #debug point
    continue
```

But in this case:

```
for j in range(10):
    k=0
    for i in range(5):
        while i==2:
            k+=1
            if k>2:
                break
        if k>2:
            break
    else:
        pass
        print('What?!')
        pass #debug point
pass
```

Versions:

Spyder 3.3.1

Python 3.6.6 64bits

QT 5.9.3

PyQT5 5.9.2

on Windows.

Comment: Make sure you are consistently using four spaces or one tab per indentation level. Don't mix and match (Python 3 doensn't allow this)! (According to PEP [it's recommended to use spaces](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces), though.)

Comment: @BramVanroy I wrote that using tabs, it's definitly consistent there. And it's reproducible.

Comment: @BramVanroy Spyder automatically converts tabs to 4 spaces

Comment: And I just counted them and it's 4 spaces per tab (so 8 to the pass)

Comment: It's no different in a regular python interpreter. Are you expecting it to throw an error?

Comment: @roganjosh I'm expecting it not to enter an else statement in debugger when breaking the for loop. And especially not to enter just the last line of an else statement

Comment: @BramVanroy how so? and if that were the case, why would it go to debug point #2 but not to #1 nor print What?!

Comment: I misread your comments in the code. Does anything follow this code? I found that adding another snippet (e.g. a continue statement) after the else (outside it) the program will not break on any of the `pass` breakpoints. It seems that the debugger breaks on the closest line it can reach if the program terminates after an unreached breakpoint.

Comment: @BramVanroy yes something does follow, I just made a minimal example here. Also, if you remove the last pass and put the debug point at the print, it won't stop there

Comment: Maybe [tracing](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/trace.html) sheds more light on the execution.